# How to force google closure compiler to keep "use strict"; in the compiled js code?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-compiler, ecmascript-5

If you're using the module pattern and have something like this:

```
(function () {
   "use strict";
   // this function is strict...
}());
```

and compile the code using the Google Closure Compiler, the `"use strict";` directive will not make it into the compiled file.

So how do you prevent the Closure Compiler from removing the ES5/strict directive?

(Note that I don't want to use the other mode of enforcing ES5/strict mode, which is to simply add the "use strict"; to the first line of the compiled file. I want to use the module pattern as described [here](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/).)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't the greatest answer, but as far as I can tell this is a known issue or "feature" (depending on your perspective) of closure compiler. Here's a [partial explanation](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=69) of some of the problems involved. A couple mentioned are that there's no way to preserve file-level strict mode declarations when multiple files are combined, and the compiler's function inlining feature would break the scope of function-level strict mode declarations. Since the behavior of "use strict" declarations would be unpredictable/wrong in compiled code (potentially breaking programs when strict mode is misapplied to non-strict code), the compiler strips them like any other dead code.

There seems to have been an idea to fully implement ECMAScript 5 strict mode checks in the compiler (in which case there would be no downside to removing it from compiled code), but it's not there yet.

Compiling in `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` mode instead of `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` will disable dead code removal, but I suspect you already know that.

Comment: Update: Ben Challenor's answer below seems to be the new "correct" answer.

Answer (score 53):

Update: strict mode is now supported in the compiler.

Just use `--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT`.

References:

http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=69

http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/detail?r=873

http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/detail?r=1114

Comment: Is there an annotation for that?

Comment: From initial investigation, it appears that the closure compiler will not strip unnecessary "use strict"; statements from concatenated files in this mode...  Worth being aware of

Comment: It also appears that it will add `'use strict';` at the top if it is not there already. Neat!

Comment: In my case only by adding `--language_out=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT` the final minification included `'use strict';`

Answer (score 8):

***Dangerous***. Closure Compiler in Advanced mode is **not** strict-mode compatible, which means that the compiler will rewrite code based on *ECMAScript 262 rev 3* rules. Some rules are changed for strict-mode (e.g. "this" binding in anonymous functions, scope resolution etc.) that will cause code breakage if Closure Compiler rewrites code incorrectly due to wrong language assumptions.

The short answer (and the Closure Compiler's official answer) is: don't do it.

If you really just want to shovel a "use strict" string there, try:

```
eval('"use strict";');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compiler's output wrapper to create the module wrapper and include the "use strict" directive there.

Answer (score 0):

Strict mode is useful for debugging, and not much else until it sees adoption into every major browser. By the time Closure Compiler removes the tag it's era of being useful is over anyway. I'm sure they'll update the compiler to allow preserving the tag long before that feature will actually be useful.