# YUI Compressor and "use strict" hint

Tags: javascript, yui-compressor, minify, use-strict

I've beeing using YUI Compressor to minify JS files. I have this code:

```
(function(global) {
    "use strict";

     var X=1;

    /*** my code here ***/

}(window));
```

And I compress it with this command:

```
$> java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar test.js -o test.min.js --verbose
```

The "use strict" hint is not present in the compressed output file. It seems that YUI removes all hints. And it output this warning:

```
[WARNING] Invalid hint syntax: use strict
(function(global){ ---> "use strict" <--- ;var X=1;...
```

Although, my code works fine after compression, I'd like  to know if there is an argument to YUICompressor to preserve the hints and/or a way to avoid that warning.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: You mean aside from just writing strict code without having the engine correct you?

Comment: wow, it really looks like YUI strips away those text hints and therefore, auto-removes any strict mode.

Comment: Go to yuilibrary.com and files a ticket for the compressor.

Comment: @Kolink, I know that once i can write full strict code I won't need the "use strict" hint. In the meantime, is useful to me to know what I'm doing that is not strict and to tell validators (jslint/jshint) that my code is supposed to be strict.

Comment: @Mörre this doesn't seem to be an error. Just want to understand what's happening there.

Comment: @Guumaster: You can file tickets for ENHANCEMENTS too, not just for "errors". So my suggestion remains :-)

Comment: @Kolink - As I understand it, the advantage of "use strict" is not just that it forces one to code better, but that it allows certain browsers to optimize code processing. So https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode claims "strict mode code can sometimes be made to run faster than identical code that's not strict mode".

Answer (score 3):

A partial explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463035/how-to-force-google-closure-compiler-to-keep-use-strict-in-the-compiled-js-co). Although that question is about closure compiler the answer gives you a hint (as Google also had this issue). In Closure it is possible to use `--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT`

Unfortunately up to now there has been no such thing for the YUI Compressor. At least I could not find anything like that.

Comment: Note that JSLint prefers the function form of 'use strict' but Closure removes the function form and adds it at the begining of the file. So still not a correct solution.