# dojo build systems does not recognize es6 syntax

Tags: dojo, ecmascript-6

I am working on a dojo project (1.11.x) and recently started using ES6(ES2015) syntax such as const, let and template literals. It worked fine until I build the project using dojo-util. I have errors like below

```
ERROR - Parse error. TypeError: redeclaration of const {variable name}
ERROR - Parse error. illegal character
                     return `<a href="/xxx/xxx/${a}">${b}</a>`;
                            ^
```

Is there any way to make the build system recognize ES6 syntax or bypass the syntax checking?

Comment: I assume you expect your code to run only on browser supporting ES6 (So no IE10 for instance) ? Otherwise, you have to transpile your ES6 into ES5 first, and it will solve your issue

Comment: BTW, I think the problem is due to the optimization (shrinksafe, closure, or uglifyjs)

Comment: Looks like this ticket https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/19020#ticket  was created one year ago and they still hadn't time for this. Sad...

Answer (score 5):

The latest release of [Dojo 1.12](https://github.com/dojo/docs/blob/master/releasenotes/1.12.rst) from December 2016 is updated to use Closure Compiler 20160911 which supports transpiling ES6 to ES5.

I have in one project older ES5 modules and new ones in ES6.

In ES6 modules you must add *"use strict"* at the beginning, otherwise building fails.

```
error(307) Failed to evaluate module tagged as pure AMD 
(fell back to processing with regular expressions). module: app/es6/Test;
error: SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class)  
not yet supported outside strict mode
```

app/es6/Dialog.js

```
"use strict"    
define(["dijit/ConfirmDialog"], (ConfirmDialog) => {
let id = '1'
const dialog = new ConfirmDialog({
    title: "Delete",
    content: `Are you sure you want to delete ${id} ?`,
    style: "width: 300px"
    })
    dialog.show()
})
```

Then in your app.profile.js add *optimizeOptions* object

```
...
optimizeOptions: {
    languageIn: 'ECMASCRIPT6',
    languageOut: 'ECMASCRIPT5'
},
layerOptimize: "closure.keeplines",
optimize: "closure.keeplines",
cssOptimize: "comments",
mini: true,
stripConsole: "all",
selectorEngine: "lite",
useSourceMaps: false,
...
layers: {
    "dojo/dojo": {
        includeLocales: [ 'en-us' ],
        include: [ "dojo/dojo", "dojo/hash" ],
        boot: true,
        customBase: true    
    }
    "app/Main": {
        includeLocales: [ 'en-us' ],
        include: [
            'app/Header',
            'app/Main'
        ]
    },
...
```

app/Main.js

```
define(["app/es6/Dialog"], function(Dialog) {
    Dialog.show();
});
```

This way you can integrate ES6 into your current Dojo project.

I was also trying to avoid "use strict" in ES6 modules by setting *languageOut: ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT* as [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463035/how-to-force-google-closure-compiler-to-keep-use-strict-in-the-compiled-js-co) but it breaks Dojo itself.

Comment: Since this is still not working for me, i asked Dojo to help out and clarify this. See https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/19020#ticket

Comment: They confirmed that this is still an open issue, so i guess we have to wait.

Comment: There is another topic at http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Dojo-build-fails-on-ES6-spread-operator-td4007121.html since Feb.

Comment: Hmm, I get `Java class "com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions$LanguageMode" has no public instance field or method named "ECMASCRIPT6"` when doing this

Comment: Take a look how integrate Dojo with Webpack and have full ES6 support https://github.com/keemor/dojo-webpack-plugin-sample

Comment: @keemor Thank you. But I’ve hard times implementing it. Do you have a step by step tutorial maybe? That would be golden, thanks :)

Comment: Also @keemor, I tried running your sample GitHub code and get errors. I reported them here: https://github.com/OpenNTF/dojo-webpack-plugin-sample/issues/72

Answer (score 1):

Since development on Dojo 1.x seems to have stalled and easy migration to Dojo 2.x is not available, we had to come up with a solution to this. It was getting ridiculous that we as developers are stuck on ES5 features, only because the build process cannot handle it.

That's why i came up with a workaround, which as of now is in test in our company. For the ones interested, this is how we work around this issue (and still use the core part of the dojo build process):

- disable optimization in the build profile (layerOptimize: false, optimize: false)
- mark all widgets as non-AMD in package.js (amd: function(){ return false;})
- this causes all widgets to get a warning in the build, but no failure
- after the build process is done, all "layers" files are complete (including ES6 features possibly), but not minified, and thus very big in size.
- in maven (or your build tool of choice), run any minifier that works for you.
- we use the latest Closure compiler with the following settings, which will transpile ES2017 code into ES5.

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <exec executable="java" resolveexecutable="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-jar" />
        <arg value="${google.closure.compiler.es2017}" />
        <arg value="--language_in=ECMASCRIPT_2017" />
        <arg value="--language_out=STABLE" />
        <arg value="--js" />
        <arg value="${dojo.build.path}/build/layers/OriginalLayer.js" />
        <arg value="--js_output_file" />
        <arg value="${dojo.build.path}/build/layers/MinifiedLayer.js" />
      </exec>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is still experimental, but first results look good and seem to work without regression.

Comment: To "mark all widgets as non-AMD in package.js": 
I know it's old, but still interested in a solution. What file is the package.js or did you mean package.json? And if so, is it allowed to define a function in the package.json? Or did you mean the packages section in the build profile?

Comment: It's described in the package section in the dojo documentation: https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/.                         
      amd: function(filename, mid) {
        return false;
      }

Comment: Btw, this approach works very well, we have been using it for years and can update to use a newer closure compiler when new syntax is available.

Comment: We have now a different solution, but this helps a lot on our painful way. Thank you.

Comment: Our solution was to let Dojo (Google Closure Compiler and Shrinksafe) do what it did  all the time, but to disable compress and minify. This job will be done by Terser. With these steps we have now ES6. And our compressed file is 30% smaller than before.

Comment: But you would still need a more recent closure compiler to allow for writing es6 code right?

Comment: No. It's working with the old one and Terser only.